# My url is working in Postman but Not working when using it from a browser?

Tags: reactjs, symfony, axios, api-platform.com

I hope you are doing fine, I have a small problem, I am devolopping an API using Symfony 4, and Working with ReactJs in the frontend, So I am sending my data to the server using axios, here is it :

```
import Axios from "axios";

const sendLoginData = (username, password) => {
  Axios.post("localhost/api/login_check", { username, password }).then(
    response => {
      console.log(response);
    }
  );
};

export default sendLoginData;
```

The data is sent right, but it seems like my route is not known I get this error in the console :

> xhr.js:166 POST http://localhost:3000/localhost/api/login_check 404
>   (Not Found)

But When I use the same url on Postman, I get my token right, which means my authentication was fine.

[image]

So, I verified some answers and found something similar to mine, a person who user .NET for the backend and was getting the same errors, but from what I understood data was sent to the server with parameters in the url, But my case is different I believe.

I don't know How to solve this, and any help would be much appreciated.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Two things: a.) ``` Axios.post("http://localhost/api/...``` or (when port of frontend and API is the same - ``` Axios.post("/api/...``` b.) down the road (when port of frontend and API are not the same): does the API return CORS headers?

Comment: What port is your API being run on? My hunch is that it is not 3000 which is what React defaults to and runs on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GET request with Basic Auth working from Postman but not from the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051366/get-request-with-basic-auth-working-from-postman-but-not-from-the-browser)

Comment: Did you try `Axios.post("//api/login_check")` ?

Comment: try changing `Axios.post("localhost/api/login_check"` to `Axios.post("http://localhost/api/login_check"`

Comment: Yes! Thank you Anuj, Nicolai, Sebastian for your answers, it is working now, Thank you Michael and Bonnie for your time, but No it is not a duplicate I believe, The person in that question was getting 401 error but it is not my case. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the scheme in your request.

In postman you are requesting `http://localhost/api/login_check`, but with axios you are requesting `http://localhost/localhost/api/login_check`.

To solve that:

```
Axios.post("http://localhost/api/login_check")
```